# Polar plots using D3.js

Tags: javascript, matlab, d3.js

Does anyone know of good examples producing a polar plot using the [D3 Javascript libraries](http://d3js.org/)?

I've seen some rose plots like [this](http://windhistory.com/station.html?CYBV) and [this](http://bl.ocks.org/3994129), but I'm really looking for something more similar to the Matlab polar plot:

[image: Matlab Polar Plot]

Any examples would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure, here you go:

[image: polar plot]

The function is plotted using [d3.svg.line.radial](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_radial). The background radial grid is implemented as line, circle and text elements. One minor annoyance is that the code needs both radians (for d3.svg.line.radial) and degrees (for SVG’s [transform attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute)). I used rotated text labels because that was easy to do with SVG, but you could use non-rotated labels if you don’t mind a little trigonometry to position the text labels.

Note carefully the definition of the line’s angle: D3’s radial lines and areas proceed clockwise starting at 12 o’clock, while this plot proceeds counterclockwise starting at 3 o’clock!

Answer (score 4):

[Plotly](https://plot.ly/api) lets you make interactive polar charts with MATLAB, Python, and R. The results are interactive, and rendered with D3.js. You can see a few MATLAB examples (code + interactive graphs) [here](https://plot.ly/matlab/polar-chart/).



[image]

[image]

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm on the Plotly team.

Comment: These are great - Any demos for the 1st and 3rd charts you shared? I don't see those in any of the docs