# Zoom/Pan D3.js Polar Scatter Plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, zooming, pan

I created a polar scatter plot using D3.js (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695073/javascript-polar-scatter-plot-using-d3-js)) .

I would like to add the functionality to zoom and pan. I've seen examples for rectangular plots, but nothing for zooming/panning on circular plots.

I am just a beginner with using D3 so I'm a little lost. Can anyone help/offer suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us what you achieved so far by making a fiddle e.g.?

Comment: Sure: https://jsfiddle.net/8opgjz45/1/

Comment: Ok, I added an answer, but I'm not entirely sure what you're aiming at...

Comment: What I meant: the points are zooming in and out, but the grid is still the same. The lines should not change and I'm not sure why the circles should change.

Comment: I added a fiddle in my answer below, I believe it is what your looking for.

Comment: I would like the ability to zoom in on specific points/areas of the graph and then pan to find the specific point of interest. Here is an example of the functionality I'm trying to accomplish, unfortunately not in a polar scatter plot format: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b418a040bb28295e4a78581fe8e269d1

Your post seems like a good start! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your goal is, but I tried something below.

First you should add zoom behaviour. I used the r scale for both your x and y directions like:

```
var zoomBeh = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(r)
    .y(r)
    .on("zoom", zoom);
```

And call the zoom behaviour into your svg:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
   .call(zoomBeh);
```

Finally you should make a zoom function.

```
function zoom() {
  var t = svg.transition().duration(750);

  svg.selectAll(".point").transition(t)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var coors = line([d]).slice(1).slice(0, -1);
        return "translate(" + coors + ")"
      })
}
```

Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3TW3/8opgjz45/3/). It's a little bit staggering, I'm not sure why yet.