# place nodes generated from a force to a radial scatter plot

Tags: d3.js

I have a force layout that generates some node positions for a given node-link diagram. My task is to place these nodes and links to a radial scatter plot. The nodes should be placed in such a way that their distance from the center node can be visible. For this reason, I calculate the euclidean distance of the nodes from the center and find maximum value from the calculated distance. Then scaled the radius of the radial plot within 0 to maximum distance value. But when I tried [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910250/how-to-find-coordinates-to-put-circle-on-polar-scatterplot-using-d3), the node-link diagram did not place upon the scatter plot. My question is how can I place the node co-ordinates to the plot such that the distance of the nodes from the center node can be seen by the circle line of the scatter plot.
Here is a portion of my input data

```
{
"nodes": [
    {
        "id": "A0",
        "group": 0,
        "degree": 19,
        "name": "x"
    },
    {
        "id": "P0",
        "group": 0,
        "degree": 3,
        "name": "y"
    },
    {
        "id": "P1",
        "group": 0,
        "degree": 3,
        "name": "z"
    },
    {
        "id": "P2",
        "group": 0,
        "degree": 1,
        "name": "w"
    }
],
"links": [
    {
        "source": "P0",
        "target": "A0"
    },
    {
        "source": "P1",
        "target": "A0"
    },
    {
        "source": "P2",
        "target": "A0"
    }
]
}
```

Here is a portion of my code.

```
var width = 1200,
  height = 800,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 30;
  //console.log(");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var rd_at = 3,
    rd_pp = 2.5;

var author_cord = [];author_cord.push({x:width / 2,y:height / 2});

var given_person = 'x';

d3.json("json_file.json", function(graph) {

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(graph.nodes)
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))//ATTRACT NODES TO CENTER(width / 2, height / 2)
    .force("x", d3.forceX(width / 2).strength(1))//X ALLIGN
    .force("y", d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(1))//Y ALLIGN
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(graph.links).id(function(d) {return d.id; ).distance(40).strength(1))
    .stop();

 var loading = svg.append("text")
       .attr("dy", "0.35em")
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
       .attr("font-size", 10)
       .text("Simulating. One moment please…");

 d3.timeout(function() {
      loading.remove();
      for (var i = 0, n = Math.ceil(Math.log(simulation.alphaMin()) / Math.log(1 -                   simulation.alphaDecay())); i < n; ++i) {
    simulation.tick();
}
var all_dist = [];
graph.nodes.forEach(function(d){
    var d_x = d.x - author_cord[0].x;
    var d_y = d.y - author_cord[0].y;

    var dist = Math.sqrt(d_x*d_x + d_y+d_y); 
    all_dist.push(dt);
});

var max_dist = d3.max(all_dist, function(d) {
  return d;
});
var r = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0,12])
          .range([0, max_dist]);    

var line = d3.lineRadial()
             .radius(function(d) {
                return r(d[1]);
             });

var gr = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "r axis")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(r.ticks(10).slice(1))
  .enter().append("g");

gr.append("circle")
  .attr("r", r);

var links = svg.append("g")
  .attr("stroke", "grey")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.target.name == given_author? 0 : 1; } )
  .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
  .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

var n = svg.append("g")
         .selectAll("circle")
         .data(graph.nodes)
         .enter().append("circle")
         .attr("r",  function(d) {return d.group == 0 ? rd_at : rd_pp;})
         .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
         .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
         .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
         .attr("stroke", "#000")//.attr("stroke", function(d) {return d.group == 0 ? "red": "blue";})
         .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {return d.group == 0 ? 1.5 : 1;});

       });
    });
```

Here is my output so far. [image: Picture]. Here, in the picture green nodes are group 0 node and orange nodes are group 1. Here, center node is the ego node that should be place in the inner most center position of the radial plot

Answer (score 0):

Your `svg` selection actually corresponds to a group already translated by half width and height:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

Therefore, you can either change the `"center"`, `"x"` and `"y"` in the simulation or, alternatively, you can just remove that group from the `svg` selection and translating the circles' groups instead:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var gr = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "r axis")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(r.ticks(10).slice(1))
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```